# How to use 2D Translation and Rotational error to get offset value for new point?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, rotations, machine-learning

Here I am trying to detect FIDUCIAL points on PCB in real time using camera.

After googling for Two days and reading many post and blog. I found that I have to do something called ***translational error detection*** and  ***rotational error detection.***

ie. Location of fiducial (object) on Image for actual() vs required(Known location)

In image below

Black Square in bottom right and Top left the Fiducial point which I need to detect and use for error check.

Here (A) is correct Image and (B) is image with error in location of fiducial point.

[image]

Now I have to draw line on image, with respect to fiducial point. So on image  A I can draw line (RED) as shown in below image (A).

But if I draw Same line on image (B), which has error due to the way it has been placed I will draw the wrong line (RED) if I use the same value of X and Y.

But here for Correct line on (B) I need to ADD ERROR value to my X and Y values so that I can draw correct line (GRREN) as shown in (B).

[image]

So here, I am trying to find out how can I archive this;

1) Detect the TWO fiducial point, get their location on Image, compare it with the correct location.

2) Find the ERROR (in Angle / in transaction/ in rotation) ?

3) use the error value by adding it X and Y values.

Any help/Guide is appreciated ...!!!
Thanks for your time.

**EDIT**

I have the Offset values, for both fidicual points, (DX1,DY1) and (DX2,DY2) is values by which original point is moved.

So, now how do I use it ? to correct the error in placement.